# My response.jsp won't populate fields properly

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css, glassfish

I been working on a web app that connects to a database which populates the designated fields. It is basically an edit of a [netbeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html). Well, I already setup the database and tested it by populating a table on the response page with all the information. THe problem arises on the index.jsp, when I pick one of the titles to view from the list. I used the titles instead of the ID numbers to select the books:

```
SELECT titlefk FROM BookList
```

instead of:

```
SELECT id, titlefk FROM BookList
```

Because the drop down box would show both the ID and the Title as the choices. After selecting a book title and clicking the submit key, it should populate the next page with the corresponding info from the database.

Pictures of the sites: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfSO4.jpg**

The table above is a temporary measure to check that the database is connected. I selected the third option on the database yet my response.jsp keeps populating with the information of the first book. I am not sure what I am missing on the code, but I hope someone could point me on the right direction.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

<sql:query var="books" dataSource="jdbc/IFPBOOKLISTRT">
SELECT titlefk FROM BookList
</sql:query>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <title>IFPBOOKLIST Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Welcome to IFPBOOKLIST, My Personal Book Selection</h1>

    <table border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Here you will find my personal books to-do list</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>To view details, select a book below</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form action="response.jsp">
                        <strong>Select a book:</strong>
                        <select name="subject_id">
                            <c:forEach var="row" items="${books.rowsByIndex}">
                                <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                                <option value="<c:out value="${column}"/>"><c:out value="${column}"/></option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
```

And here is the response.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

<sql:query var="bookQuery" dataSource="jdbc/IFPBOOKLISTRT">
    SELECT * FROM BookList,Book
    WHERE Book.id=BookList.id

</sql:query>

<c:set var="bookDetails" value="${bookQuery.rows[0]}"/>

<table border="1">
    <!-- column headers -->
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${bookQuery.columnNames}">
        <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>
<!-- column data -->
<c:forEach var="row" items="${bookQuery.rowsByIndex}">
    <tr>
    <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
        <td><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <title>${bookDetails.title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="2">${bookDetails.title}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Edition: <a href="placeholder">${bookDetails.edition}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Description: </strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                {placeholder}
            </td>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Publisher </strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                ${bookDetails.publisher}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>
                    Published Date
                </strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                ${bookDetails.datePublished}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Author </strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                ${bookDetails.author}
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>isbnNumber </strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="placeholder">${bookDetails.isbnNumber}</a>
                <br>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <strong>Amazon Link: </strong></td>
             <td>
                 <a href="placeholder">${bookDetails.amazonLink}</a>
                <br>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Let's see your response.jsp

Comment: oh right right. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is quite simple.  You should be able to whip this into shape quite easily.

- The job of the index.jsp file is to present the user with a list of
  options, allow them to select one, and then pass the selected option
  on to response.jsp.
- The job of response.jsp is to **take the selected option**, and
  display more details about it.

You're never reading the selected option, see your query in response.jsp is actually pulling all of the books and then selecting the first one returned by the database (e.g. rows[0] ):

```
<sql:query var="bookQuery" dataSource="jdbc/IFPBOOKLISTRT">
    SELECT * FROM BookList,Book
    WHERE Book.id=BookList.id
</sql:query>

<c:set var="bookDetails" value="${bookQuery.rows[0]}"/>
```

What you need to do in response.jsp is:

1) Read the subject_id parameter passed in by index.jsp.

2) Use the subject_id to filter (via a SQL WHERE clause) your bookQuery so that only the book that was selected is returned.

Returning to your tutorial, if you take a close look near the end, at item 3 below response.jsp, you'll see how they do it:

```
<sql:query var="counselorQuery" dataSource="jdbc/IFPWAFCAD">
    SELECT * FROM Subject, Counselor
    WHERE Counselor.counselor_id = Subject.counselor_idfk
    AND Subject.subject_id = ? <sql:param value="${param.subject_id}"/>
</sql:query>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did @mikey, thanks. I actually understand what I missed. Unfortunately, I added the last line (with the correct names of course) and now it won't even show the database table. I added the last line while changing **Subject** for **BookList** and **subject_id** for **id**, since that is how I set it up. The fields are not populating at all now. I would give you an up-vote but I do not have enough points to do so yet.

Comment: remember you're not passing the id over, you're passing the 'titlefk' instead.  so you're now essentially saying:  "Give me all the books with a subject id = <titlefk>"  Since subject id and titlefk are different fields, nothing matches, so the fields are not populating.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you meant, but I guess it would be better if you see it: **WHERE Book.title=BookList.titlefk AND BookList.titlefk = ?<sql:param value="${param.title}"/>** This is what I currently have and it is hasn't populated yet. I also tried **WHERE Book.title=BookList.titlefk AND BookList.titlefk = ?<sql:param value="${param.titlefk}"/>** with no luck. Sorry for not getting the obvious but I am having no luck with this yet.

Comment: The param.whatever needs to match the 'name' attribute of the select tag in the other file.  Above it is subject_id. So param.subject_id